# Printing None instead of nothing when interacting linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have a linked list where I iterate within a range and return all of the square numbers that can be represented as integers within this range. Instead of just returning just the numbers that this can be done to it will return `None` in between for example `9, None, None...,16, None, None..., 25` I wanting it to just return `9, 16, 25 etc etc`

```
class Squares:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.__start = start - 1
        self.__end = end -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return SquareIterator(self.__start, self.__end)

class SquareIterator:
    def __init__(self, start, end): 
        self.__current = start
        self.__step = 1
        self.__end = end

    def __next__(self):
        if self.__current > self.__end:
            raise StopIteration 
        else:
            self.__current += self.__step 
        x = self.__current - self.__step + 1
        self.__current - self.__step + 1
        if str(x).isdigit() and math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0:
            return x
```

Comment: Side-note: What do you think is a linked list here? Not a single thing you've done here is related to linked lists.

Comment: Are you mistaking the terms _linked list_ and _iterator_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `__next__` function continue to loop until it gets to the target value:

```
def __next__(self):
    # We're just going to keep looping. Loop breaking logic is below.
    while True:
        # out of bounds
        if self.__current > self.__end:
             raise StopIteration

        # We need to get the current value
        x = self.__current
        # increase the state *after* grabbing it for test
        self.__current += self.__step 

        # Test the value stored above
        if math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0:
             return x
```

The reason you should be storing x, then incrementing is that you have to increment no matter what, even if you don't have a perfect square.

Comment: Mind you, it would likely be *much* easier to avoid the dedicated iterator class, and just implement `__iter__` for `Squares` as a generator function. Explicit `__next__` involves all sorts of inefficient state management that Python does poorly, and isn't all that easy to follow; `__iter__` as a generator function is usually *very* straightforward; every time you hit a `yield` it's like the `return` from `__next__`, but all your state is function local, no special objects involved (generators take care of saving and restoring said local state).

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear why you are complicating things; there is a simple way:

```
import math

class Squares:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.__start = start
        self.__end = end
        self.__step = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        for x in range(self.__start, self.__end, self.__step):
            if math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0:
                yield x

s = Squares(0, 100)
for sq in s:
    print(sq, end=' ')
```

#### output:

```
0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
```

#### from the comments:

> Mind you, it would likely be much easier to avoid the dedicated
>   iterator class, and just implement `__iter__` for Squares as a generator
>   function. Explicit `__next__` involves all sorts of inefficient state
>   management that Python does poorly, and isn't all that easy to follow;
>   `__iter__` as a generator function is usually very straightforward; every time you hit a yield it's like the return from `__next__`, but all
>   your state is function local, no special objects involved (generators
>   take care of saving and restoring said local state). – ShadowRanger>

> it probably doesn't even need a Squares class. A generator function
>   named squares would do what's needed; pass it start, stop and step and
>   use them as local variables, rather than attributes of some
>   unnecessary self. Only real advantage to the class is that it could be
>   iterated repeatedly without reconstructing it, a likely uncommon use
>   case

```
def squares_from(start, stop, step=1):
    """returns a generator function for the perfect squares 
    in the range comprised between start and stop, iterated over using step=step
    """
    for x in range(start, stop, step):
        if math.sqrt(x) % 1 == 0:
            yield x

for sq in squares_from(0, 100):
    print(sq, end=' ')
```

Comment: And heck, now that you've actually written it out, I can see it probably doesn't even need a `Squares` class. A generator function named `squares` would do what's needed; pass it `start`, `stop` and `step` and use them as local variables, rather than attributes of some unnecessary `self`. Only real advantage to the class is that it could be iterated repeatedly without reconstructing it, a likely uncommon use case.

Comment: Good point; what we don't know is the ultimate purpose of this code; maybe the OP had other functionalities in mind for his class? I'll add your remark in the answer, because it makes a lot of sense.